# Big Sur restarting apps on wake from sleep

Tags: sleep-wake

This is not always the case, and maybe its the length of time in sleep, but after approximately an hour in sleep mode on waking all apps are reloaded. I loose my tabs when web browsing, apps reload without files started, and time tracking reloads (meaning I lose my current tracking data!!!). Any guidance would be welcome.

M1 Macbook Air Big Sur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a setting under *Security and privacy* > *General* > *Advanced* that was set to log me out every 45 minutes. Disabling it fixed the issue.

[image: macOS Mojave "Log out on inactivity" Screenshot]